# Convert text string into JSON format - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, text, format

I have one text string as following :

```
workingtable;AB8C;book_id;7541;
```

I would like to convert them into JSON format like : {"workingtable":"AB8C","book_id":"7541"}

Is there any JSON function so that I can convert the raw text string to JSON format like that in Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: NO, You will have to write some own custom function, how will any other third party function know where to split your plain text string

Comment: @Rex : Thanks, I can separate them by the semi colon ; so should we have the function stringify to convert them after splitting?

Comment: What you should do is create a class that will contain those fields and then use a real JSON library like JSON.Net to serialize your object to its JSON representation.

Comment: Are you looking a solution in c# or javascript?

Comment: @L.B : Hi Im looking for the solution in Javascript the data exists in the input text field which is separated by semicolon Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var s = "workingtable;AB8C;book_id;7541;";
 var parts = s.split(';');
 var jobj = {};
 for(i=0;i<parts.length;i+=2)
 {
    jobj[parts[i]]=parts[i+1];
 }
 alert(JSON.stringify(jobj));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{"workingtable":"AB8C","book_id":"7541"}
```